# Expect assert when using XCTest

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, xctest

I'm using XCTest in an Objective C project.

In my unit test target function, I use `NSAssert` to exit when receive an exception.

Even this behavior is expected, the `XCTest` still treat it as a failure.

Is there a way for `XCTest` to mark that this unit test is expected to assert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [`XCAssertThrow`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctassertthrows) macro to test for an arbitrary exception of an expression:

```objc
- (void)method {
    @throw [[NSException alloc] initWithName:@"My Exception" reason:nil userInfo:nil];
}

- (void)testThrows {
    XCTAssertThrows([self method], @"The method must throw");
}
```